# Replace passive addEventListener to onTouchStart method

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener, passive-event-listeners, ontouchstart

I want to replace `document.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, {passive: true});` to `onTouchStart={handler}`

So if I had passive flag **on true** then my handle method should like:

```
const handler = (event) => { 
    console.log(event); 
}
```

and when I have a flag **on false**:

```
 const handler = (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event); 
}
```

I'm talking about [Passive Event Listeners](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners) and browser behavior. Is it only about using `preventDefault()` or not ? 
Do I understand it correctly or not ?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners)

> Currently, browsers can't know if a touch event listener is going to cancel the scroll, so **they always wait for the listener to finish before scrolling** the page. Passive event listeners solve this problem by enabling you to set a flag in the options parameter of addEventListener indicating that the **listener will never cancel the scroll.**

This means that you change the behavior of the event. If you only change the `preventDefault`, it still have the normal behavior of the event (not passive). So this doesn't change anything.

The reason why in the docs they say to "remove" the `preventDefault` is that you need the default action of the event when setting passive to true.

This will be the normal event, without passive.

```
onTouchStart={handler}
```

This will add the passive action, but remove because of `preventDefault`

```
const handler = (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event); 
} 
...
onTouchStart={handler}
```

So you need the `.addEventListener` with `{passive: true}` and also remove any call of `.preventDefault()`.

Here is an example of how to do this in any component.

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.elementYouWant.addEventListener("touchstart", this.handleTouchStart, {passive: true});
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.elementYouWant.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.handleTouchStart);
  }

  handleTouchStart = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={e => this.elementYouWant = e}>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

I searched on how to pass the option paramenter to the event listener without needing to create it in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` in react, but coudn't find it.

You can see [here](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md#feature-detection) the best way of implementing it because some browser will interpret `{passive: true}` as `true` and this will create a different behavior.

Comment: I'm talking about https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/passive-event-listeners and browser behavior. I've got existing code (not mine) with addEventListener('touchStart') and passive flag sets to true and I want to replace it by onTouchStart, but I'm wondering if it's only about preventDefault() or there is something else more important

Comment: So you wan't to know if the only change you need to do is add or remove `preventDefault` ? And if your assumption are correct?

Comment: @Aleksandra I just edited my question, have a look :)